# Assigning value to scope in directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive that may or may not have an attribute with a value. If the user doesn't specify a value for the attribute, I want to assign a default. However, when I do that the value is always null on my scope, as with this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BwvaZLQmTJK6GMzj3RxW?p=preview)

What am I doing wrong?

Directive:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('variable', function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   template: '<h2>Directive value: {{ test  }}</h2>',
   scope: {
     test: '@'
   },
   controller: function($scope){
     $scope.test = 'code assignment'; 
   }

  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <variable></variable>
    <variable test="html assignment"></variable>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$scope.test` assignment is happening before the template is built with the directive attributes you are passing in. Because you are not declaring any `test` attribute, the directive is rendered with `$scope.test` as `undefined`.

If you just want a default value you should do the following and you will not have the need to define the controller, making your code cleaner and smaller.

```
app.directive('variable', function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   template: '<h2>Directive value: {{ test || "default value" }}</h2>',
   scope: {
     test: '@'
   }
  };
});
```

**See this [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/j3t7GC0Pm1zL8LMstXda?p=preview)**

But **if you really need** to assign default values to directive's `scope` you can use `compile` function like this:

```
app.directive('variable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<h2>Directive value: {{ test  }}</h2>',
    scope: {
      test: '@'
    },
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      if (!attrs.test) {
        attrs.test = 'default value';
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**See this [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dU2thqIWz6dGkVc04plI?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks letia, thats exactly what I was after! Haven't used the compile function yet

Comment: play around with all directive options. At first it seems complicated but it is not.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to use the link() method. That way you can check if the scope variable is null and assign a default, and then manually create the template and add it to the element. Note that the scope variable is still binded.

```
app.directive('variable', function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   replace: true,
   scope: {
     test: '@'
   },
   link: function(scope, element) {

     if(scope.test === null) {
       scope.test = 'default value';
     }

     var template = "<h2>Directive value: {{ test  }}</h2>";

     element.html(template);
   }
  };
});
```